# Why does download_app for JAVA apps fail to fetch file list everytime?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I had deployed my web application to google app engine days ago and I read from the docs that I can download the same if I'm the admin of that application(which I am). So I tried downloading that from cmd using the command(I have appengine-java-sdk-1.5.5 in place) :

```
AppCfg -A myapp -V 1 download_app C:\googleapps
```

Unfortunately, it fails me every time with the message:

> 0% Fetching file list...
>
> Error Details:
> appengine.google.com
>
> Unable to fetch file list.

Anyone who has already tried this could possibly shed some light on this and help me download the app using the above command?

EDIT: An important update- download_app works just fine from my home PC(Vista) which I'm an admin on. Only fails me on office PC where I'm NOT an admin. Could this have an impact?

Comment: 'course I did upload version 1(the only version right now) of the app with my own account. And no, the app downloads are not disabled for the app(I remember seeing a different error message if downloads were disabled).

Comment: Note that the download feature is intended for "oh god a meteor hit my laptop and I forgot to make any backups" disaster recovery, not day-to-day use. Also, in Java it will only give you the compiled code, not the source.

Comment: Lol I'm not trying to download that on day-to-day basis rather I'm trying to set up the same thing in my office PC *ONE TIME*. And yeah, I'm aware of the source code thingy not being available for download. Back on topic, any idea why this happens?